# How does one know if a question is already answered

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

Sometimes when i ask a question, i get a response that the question is already answered with a link to the answer. How does the answerer know it? I means he cannot manually  go through the Q&A database to check if my question is already answered? So how does he find that out?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you mean "This question already has an answer…" shown at the top of your question? Have you read [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: You mean that your questions are marked as duplicates? If so, it's often a sign of users spending far too much time on the site. Kidding aside, most of  my duplicate votes are because I've seen the question come by several times.

Comment: In this question, the responder pointed me to a link that already had the answer. How did he know? I would like to do the same, because it is a great feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899463/why-main-thread-has-no-shutdown-method/17899727?noredirect=1#comment26144984_17899727

Comment: Well, the site does have search functionality. But I guess I'm not far off when I say that the user probably knew what to look for. Perhaps because he had seen that post before.

Comment: If he didn't already know himself then Google always knows :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, there are several ways.

I watch for questions under certain tags, such as [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8), or [windows-runtime](/questions/tagged/windows-runtime). Generally since I see all questions for those tags, I will *sometimes* remember that the new question has already been asked.

And then there's search. If I am trying to answer a new question, I will sometimes just search (using either Google or Stack Overflow). Sometimes the results will show me similar existing questions. If the new question is similar enough to an existing one, then I just mark it as a duplicate.